# select2 - how to make sorting results: first short, then long?

Tags: jquery-select2

i use select2 The jQuery replacement for select boxes
https://select2.github.io/examples.html
what needs to change for make next sorting results: first short, then long? 
For example: 
i have next options in this sorting:

```
<option value="1">Jacksonville (Florida)</option> 
<option value="2">Florida reg.</option> 
<option value="3">Florentia</option> 
... 
<option value="9999">Florida region</option> 
<option value="5">Miami (Florida)</option>
```

1) when you type "Flo" - i see next results: 

Jacksonville (Florida) 
Florida 
Florentia 
Florida reg. 
Miami (Florida) 

2) when you type "Flori" - i see next results: 

Jacksonville (Florida) 
Florida 
Florida reg. 
Miami (Florida) 

how to do: in both cases on the top were the shortest results: 

1) 

Florida 
Florentia 
Florida reg. 
Miami (Florida) 

2) 

Florida 
Florida reg. 
Miami (Florida) 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you receive new array of suggestions from the AJAX call, you need to sort its elements by the length. Below is the code example:

```js
// this array will come from the AJAX call
var array = ['Jacksonville (Florida)', 'Florida', 'Florida reg.', 'Miami (Florida)'];
array.sort(function(a, b){return a.length - b.length});
alert(array);
// after the array is sorted you can use it for your select widget
```